# How can I get a unix timestamp x seconds from the current time in python datetime?

Tags: python

```
int (datetime.now().timestamp()) + x seconds
```

this is my understanding but how do I add the seconds?

Comment: you want to shift x second?

Comment: @Mohsen yes so current time + x seconds

Comment: check the answer that i shared. with `DIRFILTER ` all element is available and you can shift x secnd just buy  `temp.second+x`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `datetime.timedelta(seconds=x)`.

Here is a demo:

```py
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.timedelta(seconds=30)
datetime.timedelta(0, 30)
>>> datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(30)
datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 27, 7, 32, 20, 360683)
>>> (datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(30)).timestamp()
1587965562.213423
```

You can also consider [Joran Beasley’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60897994/1513933)

```
time.time() + x
```

Comment: int (datetime.timedelta(seconds=x) +datetime.now().timestamp()) --> like this?

Answer (score 1):

`time.time() + x` ... I guess you can cast to int if you need an int

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
you would have temp.second and can shift it as you desire. it is possible for any date or hour too

```
from datetime import datetime

temp = datetime.now()
DIRFILTER = "{:04d}{:02d}{:02d} {:02d}:{:02d}:{:02d}".format(temp.year, temp.month, temp.day,temp.hour,temp.minute,temp.second)
shifted_second=temp.second+20 //desire second
print(temp)
print(DIRFILTER)
print(shifted_second)
```

Output:(20 second added to current Second)

```
2020-03-28 11:12:31.418328
20200328 11:12:31
51
```